# Horizontal Scroll bar for Navigation pane in Word 2013?

Tags: microsoft-word

Is there an available horizontal scroll bar for use in the Navigation Pane of Word 2013?  I have a large document that has a lengthy and many-tiered "Headings" section.  The Navigation Pane entries are obscured because of the many heading levels and the width of the navigation pane.  I didn't create the document.

I've been searching but I haven't been able to find a way to enable the appearance of a horizontal scroll bar (or if one even exists).

Does anyone have any information as to whether a vertical scroll bar for the Navigation Pane of Word 2013 exists and, if it does, how I can enable it?

Thanks in advance.